# Combine two Series into one column of a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two series and I want to verify if both of them have a value, so I can put a comma in between the values. This way it will look more organized the final result. Right now when I merge the two series into one column of the Dataframe it looks messy.

This is how I'm doing:

```
series1 = df_grouped['mismatchMom'].apply(lambda g: g.any() + ' with mother' if g.any() else None)
series2 = df_grouped['mismatchDad'].apply(lambda g: g.any() + ' with father' if g.any() else None)

df_individual['mismatch'] = series1 + ', ' + series2
```

It works, but whenever there is no value in series1, or in series2 or no value both of them the comma looks really weird.

I tried to do something like this:

```
df_individual['mismatch'] = series1 + ', ' + series2 \
        if series1.bool() & series2.bool() else \
        series1 + series2
```

(I tried replacing `bool()` to `isnull()` as well) but I get the error

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Thanks!

Comment: just one question, when you say "no value", you mean None, np.nan or '' ?

Comment: `None` from the first two lines of the code I posted

Comment: yeah just as I thought, so is it okey if you change None in those lines to '' ? or are they necessary to be None? that way it would be really easy ^^'

Comment: Yes, there is no problem at all. I guess I see where you are going. You would use .str.join()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this if you want: (if you s1 and s2 have same size)

```
df['mismatch'] = pd.concat([s1,s2],axis = 1).apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x) if not x.all() == '' else x.sum(),axis=1)
```

I only asked to change `None` because the if statement would be this simple like that.

The idea is to [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) the two series by column and simply join the rows if there are no `empty strings`. If there are we just sum the rows elements.

That way you can get an output like :

```
       A     B mismatch
0  stuff  more   aa, aa
1  stuff  more       bb
2  stuff  more       cc
3  stuff  more         
4  stuff  more   ee, ee
```

without the weird `,`.

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: That was smart. Sorry it took so long to respond, but there was a different section of my code which was rewriting part of it. Now I just have to replace all the None (np.nan) to `''`. Thanks!